# Alexa: productId, code challenge: what should they be?

Tags: ios, xcode, authorize, alexa-skills-kit

I am following closely [this document](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-voice-service/docs/authorizing-your-alexa-enabled-product-from-an-android-or-ios-mobile-app) to authorize a hardware from my iOS app:

In iOS section, at step 5):

```
- (IBAction)onLogInButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSArray *requestScopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"alexa:all", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSString* scopeData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"alexa:all\":{\"productID\":\"%@\","
                           "\"productInstanceAttributes\":{\"deviceSerialNumber\":\"%@\"}}}",
                           productId, deviceSerialNumber];
    options[kAIOptionScopeData] = scopeData;
    options[kAIOptionReturnAuthCode] = @YES;
    options[kAIOptionCodeChallenge] = @"CODE_CHALLENGE_GOES_HERE";
    options[kAIOptionCodeChallengeMethod] = @"S256";

    [AIMobileLib authorizeUserForScopes:requestScopes delegate:delegate options:options];
}
```

what should `productId` in scopeData be? As I have read some other posts, it is said that `productId` is taken from ID column of an app created in [AVS Developer Portal](https://developer.amazon.com/edw/home.html#/avs/list), which is not linked with the document as it mentions to [App Console](http://login.amazon.com/manageApps) in [Getting Started guide for iOS](http://login.amazon.com/ios#install_login_with_amazon_library). So I am confused at how/where to take the `productId`.

`deviceSerialNumber` can be any unique string?

I implemented a code-challenge method in ObjC based on item 1) and 2) described in "Transferring an Authorization Code from a Mobile App to an Alexa-enabled Product" section. Is it correct? (since I have no reference example)

```
- (NSString *)codeChallenge {
    verifier = [NSString randomStringWithLength:128]; // generate 128-char string containing [A-Z], [a-z], [0-9], "-", "_", ".", "~"
    NSData *sha256 = [[verifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] SHA256]; // SHA256 that string
    NSString *base64Enc = [sha256 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]; // base64 encode SHA256 result
    NSLog(@"base64Enc: %@", base64Enc);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<base64Enc.length; i++) { // remove "="; replace "+" with "-"; replace "/" with "_" as referenced from: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-spop-10#appendix-A
        unichar c = [base64Enc characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c == '=') {
            continue;
        }
        else if (c == '+') {
            [ret appendString:@"-"];
        }
        else if (c == '/') {
            [ret appendString:@"_"];
        }
        else {
            [ret appendFormat:@"%C", c];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out that the `App ID` is the `productID`. You should able able find yours on Developer Console under Application Type Info tab. Your code challenge seems fine to me, but I'm not sure why you'd want to strip off `=+-_`. And yeah, `deviceSerailNumber` could be anything unique, I'm assuming that it should also be unique per installation.

The following in the Swift example for the same,

```
  @IBAction func loginWithAmazon() {
    let scopes = ["alexa:all"];
    let codeChallenge = sha256("CODE_CHALLENGE_GOES_HERE".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!).base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    var options: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
    let scopeData = String(format: "{\"alexa:all\":{\"productID\":\"%@\",\"productInstanceAttributes\":{\"deviceSerialNumber\":\"%@\"}}}", "yourAppIDHere", "anyUniqueID")
    options[kAIOptionScopeData] = scopeData;
    options[kAIOptionReturnAuthCode] = true;
    options[kAIOptionCodeChallenge] = codeChallenge;
    options[kAIOptionCodeChallengeMethod] = "S256";

    AIMobileLib.authorizeUserForScopes(scopes, delegate: self, options: options);
  }

  func requestDidSucceed(apiResult: APIResult!) {
    accessToken = apiResult.result
    print(apiResult.result)
  }

  func requestDidFail(errorResponse: APIError!) {
    print(errorResponse.error)
  }
  =================================================
  func sha256(data : NSData) -> NSData {
    var hash = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    CC_SHA256(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &hash)
    let res = NSData(bytes: hash, length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
    return res
  }
```